# Replace timestamps in a notepad++ file

Tags: notepad++, timestamp, gps

I have these GPX files that I want to change the time in, and I'm not sure how to automate it.

```
    <time>2018-10-25T18:00:00Z</time>
    <time>2018-10-25T18:02:24Z</time>
    <time>2018-10-25T18:03:35Z</time>
```

There are about 70 of these lines in every file and about 25 files. Currently, the total timespan is 1 hour and 26 minutes but I want to make it shorter, 26 minutes long. I figured that I could use the replace function in notepad++ but I'm not very proficient in coding, and so I'm not sure how to automate this otherwise tedious process.

Currently the first line of code says `<time>2018-10-25T18:00:00Z</time>` and the last one says `<time>2018-10-25T19:27:28Z</time>`, and there are 70 lines in between. I would like to make so that I can change the last line to `<time>2018-10-25T18:26:00Z</time>`and change all the ones in between so that they fit accordingly.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you wish to change the times to? Use the EDIT button to add this to your question.

Comment: NP++ is not really the tool for this, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912184/is-it-possible-to-replace-text-automatically-in-notepad-from-the-command-line). It's comparatively easy to do in LInux, so you should investigate Windows ports of `bash`, `date` and `sed`. You can use WSL on Windows 10, or CygWin on most Windows versions. You can also find individual ports, `bash.exe`, `date.exe` and `sed.exe`.

Comment: Okay, I will investigate. Thank you again for helping me out!